# Selenium.Click failing

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have a page using Selenium IDE and RC. This is a results page, and  has a bunch of results with checkboxes in front. On top of the page, there are options to Select All, and Clear All. After clicking on the Select All, I get a javascript alert saying "Are you sure you want to select all....?". The HTML/CSS for this is something like:

1) Select All

2) Clear All

When I right-click on Select All and Clear All, and do Inspect Element, the xpath is:

1) /html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span

2) /html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span[2]

```
selenium.Click("xpath=(/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span)");
```

is giving me Error: Element xpath=(/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span not found

```
selenium.Click("//span[@onclick=\"fnCheckGroupWithMessage(''Are you sure you want to select all?', 'cbxRepeater_');\"]");
```

is giving me Error: Permission denied

I am not sure why selenium.Click is failing for Select All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
selenium.Click("xpath=(/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span)");
```

try

```
selenium.Click("xpath=/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span");
```